# CSS3 animate border color

Tags: css

I want to animate borders of an element using CSS3, whether it's in hover state or normal state. Can someone provide me a code snippet for this or can guide?

I can do this using jQuery but looking for some pure CSS3 solution.

Answer (score 83):

You can use a CSS3 `transition` for this. Have a look at this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ujDkf/1/

Here is the main code:

```
#box {
  position : relative;
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  background-color : gray;
  border : 5px solid black;
  -webkit-transition : border 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition : border 500ms ease-out;
  -o-transition : border 500ms ease-out;
  transition : border 500ms ease-out;
}

#box:hover {
   border : 10px solid red;   
}
```

Answer (score 35):

You can try this also...

```css
button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #f45e61;
  color: #f45e61;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
button::before, button::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.draw {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s;
  transition: color 0.25s;
}
.draw::before, .draw::after {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.draw::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.draw::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.draw:hover {
  color: #60daaa;
}
.draw:hover::before, .draw:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.draw:hover::before {
  border-top-color: #60daaa;
  border-right-color: #60daaa;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
  transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}
.draw:hover::after {
  border-bottom-color: #60daaa;
  border-left-color: #60daaa;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s;
  transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s;
}
```

```html
<section class="buttons">
  <button class="draw">Draw</button>
</section>
```

Comment: This is awesome and is exactly what I've been looking for. Anyway to apply this exact effect to an entire table row though?

Answer (score 13):

If you need the transition to run infinitely, try the below example:

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: block;
}

#box:hover {
  border-color: red;
  animation-name: flash_border;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: flash_border;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: flash_border;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes flash_border {
  0% {
    border-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: red;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash_border {
  0% {
    border-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: red;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes flash_border {
  0% {
    border-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box">roll over me</div>
```

Comment: Heya @Tahir. As a heads up, answers should be self-contained; while they can _refer_ to external sources as references, the answer information shouldn't exist solely on external sites. Because of that, I brought your JSFiddle code into the answer itself, converted the SCSS to CSS and renamed the animation name to `flash_border` (because the `flash` name was conflicting with something on Stack Overflow's side).

Comment: Nice... From your code I make an auto run with duration and infinite:
http://jsfiddle.net/913xjzL6/24/

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to this one but...

This is what I do:

```css
.class {
  color: tomato;
  border: 10px solid currentColor;
  transition: color 250ms linear;

  // not part of solution just layout
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.class:hover {
  color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div class='class' >color way</div>
```