# CSS triangle to transition between two colors

Tags: javascript, css

I have a triangle made in CSS and I want it to slowly transition between two colors **without** the use of a `hover` state.

```
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid $mgrey;
 }
```

I've tried putting something like `transition: color 0.3s;` but that does not seem to work. Would I have to use JavaScript to achieve the affect I'm after or can it be done in pure CSS?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476923/css3-animate-border-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS `transition`, you should set the transition for `border-color` property instead of the `color`.

```css
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid red;
    
    transition: border-color 0.2s linear; /* Or border-top-color */
}
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/3L65h/)**.

### Update

> I meant without the use of a hover state. So it just slowly
> transitions on the page without having to interact with it.

According to your update, you could use [CSS3 animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) (as @arty suggested) to animate the `border-color`:

```css
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid red;

    animation: borderColor 2s forwards;
 }

@keyframes borderColor
{
    0%   {border-top-color: red;}
    100% {border-top-color: gold;}
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/3L65h/2/)**.

Or use JavaScript to add a `.hover` class to the element and use the `transition` approach as follows:

```css
.arrow-down {   
    transition: border-color 2s; /* Or border-top-color */
}

.arrow-down.hover {   
    border-top-color: gold;
}
```

Using jQuery [`.addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method:

```javascript
$('.arrow-down').addClass('hover');
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/3L65h/3/)**.

Comment: Oh sorry I don't think I specified correctly. I meant without the use of a hover state. So it just slowly transitions on the page without having to interact with it.

Comment: use css3 keyframes, example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224047/continuous-css-transitions

Comment: @user2933987 I've updated the answer to fit your needs.

Comment: @HashemQolami This is perfect. How would I get it so when I apply infinite to the animation it animates back to the first state instead of jumping back?

Comment: Never mind. It can be done with animation-direction: alternate;

Comment: @faooful You could use the `alternate` value for `animation-direction`: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/3L65h/4/